# ASP.NET MVC Ajax submit form with AntiforgeryToken and Serialized Form data with Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to submit a form via ajax like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#form").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', this).val();
            var form_data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("SaveRole", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())",
                method: "POST",
                data: form_data,
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
            return false;
            console.log(form_data);
        });
    });
```

This contacts this controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAjax]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SaveRole(SaveRolesDetailsViewModel Input)
    {
        //var role = rolesData.GetByName(Input);
        var result = this.Json(new
        {
            Output = Input
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        return result;
    }
```

Right now, I'm getting errors that my RequestVerificationToken field is not being submitted but I'm not sure how I can combine it with my form data. By default, when I serialize my form data, it already sends this token but for some reason my controller still fails it.

Also, how do I use the modelstates to show my form validations? Right now they are returned as json objects.

EDIT:

AjaxValidate Attribute:

```
public class ValidateAjax : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                return;

            var modelState = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState;
            if (!modelState.IsValid)
            {
                var errorModel =
                        from x in modelState.Keys
                        where modelState[x].Errors.Count > 0
                        select new
                        {
                            key = x,
                            errors = modelState[x].Errors.
                            Select(y => y.ErrorMessage).
                            ToArray()
                        };
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult()
                {
                    Data = errorModel
                };
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I submit an empty form, this is what is returned:

```
0:{key: "RoleName", errors: ["The Role Name field is required."]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the jQuery `.serialize()` method, it generates query string format (i.e. `..&name=value&...`, which needs to be sent using the default `contentType` - i.e `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`.

Remove the `contentType: "application/json",` from the ajax options.

In addition, your `var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', this).val();` line of code is not necessary - the token is included when you use `.serialize()`

```
$("#form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Add the following if you have enabled client side validation
    if (!$(this).valid()) {
        return;
    }
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("SaveRole")",
        method: "POST",
        data: form_data,
        success: function (result) {
            ... // see notes below
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
    // return false; not necessary since you have used e.preventDefault()
    console.log(form_data);
});
```

To return `ModelState` errors, remove your `ValidateAjaxAttribute` - returning a `BadRequest` is not appropriate (which is intended to *indicate that the server could not understand the request due to invalid syntax*).

Instead modify the POST method to return a `JsonResult` that includes the errors (note there is no need to return the model)

```
public ActionResult SaveRole(SaveRolesDetailsViewModel Input)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
    else
    {
        var errors = ModelState.Keys.Where(k => ModelState[k].Errors.Count > 0).Select(k => new { propertyName = k, errorMessage = ModelState[k].Errors[0].ErrorMessage });
        return Json(new { success = false, errors = errors });
    }
}
```

Then in the success callback, if there are errors, loop through them and find the corresponding `<span>` element generated by your `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` and update its contents and class names

```
success: function (result) {
    if (result.success) {
        return;
    }
    $.each(result.errors, function(index, item) {
        // Get message placeholder
        var element = $('[data-valmsg-for="' + item.propertyName + '"]');
        // Update message
        element.append($('<span></span>').text(item.errorMessage));
        // Update class names
        element.removeClass('field-validation-valid').addClass('field-validation-error');
        $('#' + item.propertyName).removeClass('valid').addClass('input-validation-error');
    });
},
```

Comment: As for the `ModelState` errors, you need to show how you return that data in your POST method

Comment: Hey, thanks! And I'll edit the question to include the method to return ajax validation issues.

Comment: You method is not returning `ModelState` errors (its just returning your model). And you should not be returning a `BadRequest` just because `ModelState` is invalid

Comment: Hi, if I just use something like ModelState.valid would that be enough? And yes, the message placeholders are generated by @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.property). Thank you for your help.

Comment: Will try it out. Thanks!